# can an online application connect with a local offline server?? (maybe with javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, connection

I created a web application and I want to connect the web application to a "dongle".
The problem is: I found out, that the dongle has no mobile connection and ist NOT connected to the internet.

The setup is this:
I have an iPad. The iPad connects to the dongle via WIFI and connects to the web application via LTE (mobile data).
This is working.

Actually I wanted to connect to the dongle via curl.
But since the dongle is offline and just accessible in the local network, this is not working... of course....

So, since javascript runs on the client side, I was wondering, if there is a way to connect to a local server via javascript.
I found socket.io, but I'm not sure, if this is gonna solve the problem...

Can somebody give me a hint and say "yeah, sure that's possible, use that tool" or "Nope, sorry, you gotta find another way for this" or even more helpful things...

Comment: The dongle is part of the local network? If the iPad connects to it via WiFi then anything *should* be able to connect to it via WiFi.

Comment: If you have server code running on the same network as the dongle, you could use client side js to make a request to server which could then connect to the dongle

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. Yes, the dongle is part of the local network, but the script is on the server of the webspace provider. So I can't connect to the dongle from there. Servercode is not running on the same server. That's why I thought of java script, because it is running on clientside (in this case the iPad)... but I didn't find any js methods or plugins to connect to the local network

Comment: It is irrelevant _how_ you make the request, be it `cURL` or `javascript`. You have a routing issue, you need to tell your system what requests to send through what network connections.

Comment: I got the request url and testet it using the browser address. Works. Getting the result I want to have. But I need the data in my webApp... It may not matter _how_ I make the request, but it matters _where_ I do that. If I use curl in my web app, it will be executed on server side and has NO connection to my local network (which is not connected to the internet). If I use javascript and probably an Ajax call to the local ip (hey..... worth a shot) it will be executed on client side and I can maybe reach the dongle.... I need to try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long ago, but:
The solution to this was really easy.
I just used Ajax to connect, because javascript works on client side and was able to connect with the device in the local network!